# CMAKE: How to add a dependency to the link phase of the add_executable() command?

Tags: cmake, linker-scripts

I would like to build an executable with a specific linker script file (`my.linkcmds`).
And when I update my linker script, I would like to trigger the linker part of the `add_executable()`.

I use the following `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.22)
project (HELLO)

set(LNK_SCRIPT ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/my.linkcmds)
add_custom_target(hello_linkcmd DEPENDS ${LNK_SCRIPT})

add_executable       (hello main.c)
target_link_libraries(hello -T ${LNK_SCRIPT})
add_dependencies     (hello hello_linkcmd)
```

Problem: When I update my.linkcmds, it just updates the main target but not redo the link phase.

```
$ touch ../my.linkcmds
$ make
[  0%] Built target hello_linkcmd
[100%] Built target hello
```

My current workaround is to set the dependency to the source file to trigger the `main.o` rebuild and force the hello relink, but it is not elegant because source recompilation is not needed in this case!

```
set_source_files_properties(main.c OBJECT_DEPENDS ${LNK_SCRIPT_TEMPLATE})
```

What is the best way to add a dependency to the link phase of the `add_executable()` command ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the solution was already on stackoverflow! (Thanks KamilCuk)

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.22)
project (HELLO)

set(LNK_SCRIPT ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/my.linkcmds)

add_executable       (hello main.c)
target_link_libraries(hello -T ${LNK_SCRIPT})
set_target_properties(hello PROPERTIES LINK_DEPENDS ${LNK_SCRIPT})
```

Works well!